# Infinite Scroll Displaying Duplicate Results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I've been create infinite scroll on Laravel through ajax

i have a div class as canvas called **.canvasContent** .

here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="row canvasContent"></div>
```

then here is my ajax request when the page reload for first time, it's will be execute it :

```
var offset = 0;

  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/category/get_data_category",
          data: {
                  'category'  : 'entertainment',
                  'offset':0,
                  'limit':2,
                  '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
          success: function(data) {
            $('.canvasContent').append(data);
            offset +=2;
          }
  });
```

and if the user scrolling page, will be execute :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.canvasContent').height()) 
    {
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/category/get_data_category",
              data: {
                      'category'  : 'entertainment',
                      'offset'    : offset,
                      'limit'     : 2,
                      '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    },
              success: function(data) 
              {
                $('.canvasContent').append(data);
                offset +=2;
              }
      });
    }
```

the ajax request have params offset and limit and i pass to the controller and draw the html in controller , here is my controller code :

```
        $offset             = $request->offset;
        $limit              = $request->limit;
        $data               = [];

        $category           = $request->category;
        $dataCat            = Categorymodel::get_category_by_name($category,$limit,$offset);

        $html = "";
        foreach ($dataCat as $key => $data) 
        {

            $image = GlobalController::get_single_image($data->id);
            $html =' <div class="col-md-6" id="post-id" id="'.$data->id.'">
                        <article class="entry">
                          <div class="entry__img-holder">
                            <a href="'.route('detail', $data->slug).'">
                              <div class="thumb-container thumb-75">
                                <img data-src="'.'/'.$image[0]->image.'" src="img/empty.png" class="entry__img lazyload" alt="">
                              </div>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                       /**blah blah blahh **/
                      echo $html;
          }
```

category name,offset and limits pass to a method on model called 
**get_category_by_name**, 
here is my model code :

```
public static function get_category_by_name($cat_name,$limit,$offset)
    {
        $category = DB::table('article')
                    ->select("article.*","category.id as cat_id","category.name")
                    ->where("category.name",$cat_name)
                    ->where("article.status",'active')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->join("category","article.category_id", "=", "category.id")
                    ->orderBy('article.created_at','desc')
                    ->get();

        return $category;
    }
```

i've limit and offset there, but why the result always duplicate like this ? [image]

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Try this solution, maybe it will be easier for you: https://laraget.com/blog/implementing-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-laravel-and-jscroll

Comment: ok, the infinite scroll working now, but the posts data are small ..

Answer (score 1):

You are doing mistake in your "get_category_by_name" function :

you are fetching records with offset and limit with out tracking your last article id.

You have to do change as I do in your function:

```
public static function get_category_by_name($last_article_id,$cat_name,$limit,$offset)
{
    $category = DB::table('article')
                ->select("article.*","category.id as cat_id","category.name")
                ->where("article.id",">", $last_article_id) //New Change 
                ->where("category.name",$cat_name)
                ->where("article.status",'active')
                ->limit($limit)
                ->offset($offset)
                ->join("category","article.category_id", "=", "category.id")
                ->orderBy('article.created_at','desc')
                ->get();

    return $category;
}
```

Comment: it's show me error message : Illegal operator and value combination. Iam using Laravel 5.6

Comment: I have not executed this code but You have to do like this.I try to edit this again.

Comment: For this your "article"  table ID must be an integer value.